# Unable to run Rake tasks, ci_reporter dependency missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, rake

I am unable to any `rake` tasks within my Rails project. Any attempt to do so results in the following error, stating that it cannot locate an rspec file for ci_reporter:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ci/reporter/rake/rspec
/Users/blake/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/blake/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/blake/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/blake/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/blake/workspaces/ruby/minestatus/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/blake/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
```

I have made the following attempts to reset my environment to a working state:

- Installing the newest `ci_reporter` gem from github
- Deleting Gemfile.lock and re-running `bundle install`
- Reinstalling Ruby 2.0.0 using rvm

Unfortunately none of the above things have helped me solve this issue. I am able to run `rake` tasks in other Rails projects, but not in this one. Rake tasks used to run just fine, and I'm not sure what changes I could've made to break things. Does anyone have an idea of what I can do to get `rake` tasks to run properly again?

Comment: I actually just fixed the issue by removing `require 'ci/reporter/rake/rspec'` from my Rakefile. Does anyone know if there are negative repercussions for doing so?

Comment: The gem might be used for integrating your rspec tests output with your CI system, to output meaningful reporting on the CI jobs run (which could be now broken sine you have removed it). Are you bundling the gems in any particular scope (prod, dev, test etc)?